# I/O Monad and ByteString to Char conversion?

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I'm testing some HTTP requests in haskell and have the below methods:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LAZ
import  Language.Haskell.TH.Ppr
import System.IO
import Data.Word (Word8)

request :: IO LAZ.ByteString
request = do
     response <- simpleHttp "https://www.url.com"
     return (response)

exampleFunctionOne:: IO LAZ.ByteString -> IO LAZ.ByteString
exampleFunctionOne bytes = do 
     html <- bytes
     let bytesToChars = bytesToString $ LAZ.unpack html
     let x = exampleFunctionTwo bytesToChars
     bytes

exampleFunctionTwo :: [Char] -> [Char]
exampleFunctionTwo chars = --Do stuff...

main = do
  exampleFunctionOe $ request
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a more straight forward way to convert the ByteString to [Char]? Currently I've having to convert to perform (ByteString -> Word8) and then (Word8 -> Char)
2. Am I correct in saying the 'return ()' statement in my request function is simply re-applying the monad context (in this case IO) to the value I've extracted (response <- simpleHttp)? Or does it have an additional purpose?

Comment: Be careful here. A byte-string is NOT actually convertible to a list of characters, unless we know its encoding. `Char8` assumes latin-1, which is arbitrary. AFAICS, the general trend is using utf8 for most of the text around the net. In html for instance, the encoding is sometimes declared inside the html itself, which makes everything a bit more complex. I hope there is a library that handles this semi-transparently somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, note that there's a different "unpack" in Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 with the signature you want:

```
unpack :: ByteString -> String
```

It's not unusual for people to import both modules:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C
```

and mix and match functions from each.

To answer your second question, yes that's more or less it.  For example:

```
redund = do x <- getLine
            y <- return x
            z <- return y
            u <- return z
            return u
```

is all equivalent to `redund = getLine` with a bunch of re-wrapping and extracting of pure values into an out of an IO monad.